# Understanding Axis2 Endpoints

Tags: java, web-services, soapui, apache-axis, axiom

I'm attempting to consume a SOAP web service, now, the example I've been given is using SoapUI.

The endpoint at the top points to https://www.URL-A/example.ashx but then the addressing module (wsa:To) points to https://www.URL-B/example.svc.

What is the URL at the top of soapUI? and why is there a different endpoint in the addressing module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the URL at the top of soapUI?

That is the URL where the request is really sent

> and why is there a different endpoint in the addressing module?

In the addressing - effectively there can be anything (any URL) and in most of the time this information is ignored.

The purpose of the addressing is to provide some addressing information (To, ReplyTo, messageId, ..) independently from the protocol (http). So the message could be resent by different protocols (e.g. using JMS) passed to different endpoints, etc.

Long story short - you should pay attention what's in the soapUI top field, that's the reals endpoint where the request will be sent.

Comment: That's great, that has really helped clearing it up. I'm finding it pretty difficult to find documentation on all of this. Thanks for that Gusto2!